# Hidden packages (after upgrade to Fedora 33?)

Tags: haskell, fedora, ghc

I just upgraded to Fedora 33, and at least for Data.Vector and System.Random, I am getting stuff like:

```
Prelude> import Data.Vector

<no location info>: error:
    Could not load module ‘Data.Vector’
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘vector-0.12.1.2’.
    You can run ‘:set -package vector’ to expose it.
    (Note: this unloads all the modules in the current scope.)
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: I upgraded another system, and both modules are fine. Maybe some local cabal misconfiguration?

EDIT 2: `ghc-pkg list` shows both packages as non-hidden (ie they are not in parenthesis). What is overriding this?

EDIT 3: Removing .ghc/x86_64-linux-8.8.4/environments/default solves the issue. By looking at it, not all system packages are listed. Do I need that? How was it generated?

EDIT 4: The problem seems to be that `cabal install --lib` creates a default environment which does not include all the system packages. I'll file a bug...

Comment: You should run it with `ghci -package vector`, or use `:set -package vector` to do that in the session you already started.

Comment: Well, sure :P But it was not like that before.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the root cause but I would warn against using bare `ghci` on a modern Haskell install.  Instead I would suggest `cabal v2-repl --build-depends vector` to ensure  a compatible `vector` package is loaded.

Comment: Can you elaborate as to why? I am getting lots of suggestions to drop ghci, but for me it has been working fine. I am not saying that the advice is not sound! But I have not found proper explanations.

Comment: Suppose you install `foo` and it depends on `bar-1.0` and then you install `baz` and it depends on `bar-1.1`. You load `ghci`. Which version of `bar` should it expose? It can't expose both (if `foo` and `baz` export symbols from it). Should it expose `foo` or `baz`? It can't expose both. This is what was called "cabal hell".  Since cabal version 2 "cabal hell" no longer exists. Part of the reason is that cabal can determine exactly which dependencies you need and expose a maximally compatible set, downloading and compiling if necessary. But that means you have to use `ghci` *through* `cabal`.

Comment: OK, thanks, that is a great explanation :-) I am very conservative with the packages I use, and very seldom need anything cutting edge. When I run into that I will know what to do.